# no ros workspace

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner with ROS.  I am trying the tutorials, and I do not find ros workspace in the ros directory.  Do I have to create it?

Thanks,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11816/no-ros-workspace/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you have to create the directory ros_workspace. Go to your /home/user directory and type

mkdir ros_workspace

Look at the link below for more details.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

---

Originally posted by [AlgorithmSeeker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1323/algorithmseeker/) with karma: 46 on 2011-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3